# C stack corrupted for a string var

Tags: c, stack

So as a part of a class project, I'm supposed to receive an input string from the user and to varies actions on it. For some reason, I get a stack corrupted error in the following code.

```
void main()
{
char cmd[80] = "", substr[81] = "", matrixName1[11], matrixName2[11], substrFrob[11] = "";
int start = 0, end = 0, cmdSort, i, j, prog = 0, row = 0, col, row1, row2, col1, col2, **matrix1, **matrix2, trace = 0, words, matrixNum = 0;
memset(matrixName1, 0, strlen(matrixName1));                //reseting variables
memset(matrixName2, 0, strlen(matrixName2));
printf_s("@");
fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin);
words = wordCounter(cmd);
start = end;
stringCutter(substr, cmd, &start, &end);
while (1)
{
    if (prog == 0)                                                  //sorting for command and number of args
    {
        if (!strcmp(substr, "exit") && words == 1) break;
        else if (!strcmp(substr, "zeroes") && words == 4) cmdSort = 1;
        else if (!strcmp(substr, "set") && words > 1) cmdSort = 2;
        else if (!strcmp(substr, "echo") && words == 2) cmdSort = 3;
        else if (!strcmp(substr, "frob") && words == 3) cmdSort = 4;

/* rest of the code*/

if (matrixName1[0] != 0)            //freeing memory
{
    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
        free(matrix1[i]);
    free(matrix1);
}
if (matrixName2[0] != 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < row2; i++)
        free(matrix2[i]);
    free(matrix2);
}
//system("cls");
//exit(0);
```

now as a part of the project we can't use any function within stdlib.h expect malloc and free. once I removed the exit(0), I started to receive an error when the user enters "exit" -
"Run time check Failure #2  stack around the variable 'substr' was corrupted"
but for the life of me, I can't find whats wrong.

thank in advence.

Comment: 'strlen(matrixName1)' !  strlen() != sizeof

Comment: You call `strlen` on an uninitialized char array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't check your code but it's likely that you are not allocating enough space for the char arrays. Trying to write to the char array that was not previously allocated can corrupt stack cookies hence the error. 
If you had provided the full code I would try running it. In this case I can only guess :)

Edit: You might not be using the strlen right. You should be using "sizeof(char) * charcount " instead on memset calls.

Comment: I can send you the full code if you like, but the  problem is when the input is "exit"

Comment: In the end, the problem was in the strlen. The sizes were bigger than needed to be which caused stack problems.
Thank you very much.